# powershell first argument is of type object[]?

Tags: powershell

If i run the following code in PowerShell ISE

```
cls
Function XmlTransformaton ($sourceFile, $targetFile, $xsltFile)
{
    echo "sourceFile: " + $sourceFile.GetType();
    echo "targetFile: $targetFile";
    echo "xsltFile: $xsltFile";
}
XmlTransformaton("C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.rdl", "C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.rdl", "C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.xslt");
```

i get the following output

```
sourceFile: 
+

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType                                          
-------- -------- ----                                     --------                                          
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array                                      
targetFile: 
xsltFile:
```

Why on earth is the first argument of type array? The result of this is that all other parameters are empty!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're passing an array as your first (and only) argument. It looks like you want to be doing this instead:

```
XmlTransformaton "C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.rdl" "C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.rdl" "C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.xslt"
```

Which gives:

```
sourceFile:
+

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
targetFile: C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.rdl
xsltFile: C:\temp\TransfromTest\Test.xslt
```

Multiple arguments are passed to functions as `Some-Function $param1 $param2 $paramN`, no need to use parenthesis and comma separated args - that's how you construct an array